# Why C# switch only runs the first statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have the following switch statement, and when the string `foo = "FOO"` then the case will trigger two `MessageBoxes`. But I only get "**Dog**" popped up and not "**Cat**". For some reason, the case only run the first statement then break itself. Why is that?

```
switch(foo)
{
   case "FOO"
      MessageBox.Show("Dog");
      MessageBox.Show("Cat");
      break;
   case ...
   case ...
}
```

Comment: I don't know if its the solution but you forgot to add the : after "FOO" !

Comment: What message you want to show in MessageBox ?

Comment: I tested your code and I see both *Dog* and *Cat*.

Comment: He wants to show two message boxes, the first one displaying "Dog", the second one displaying "Cat" - only "Dog" is displayed. No falling through the switch statement, and it's also pretty clear what message he wants to show if you read the question...

Comment: Your example works fine for me (provided you add the ":")

Comment: I cannot delete this question because of answers. I'm voting to delete my own question, It's completely not constructive. the problems are threading bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unable to reproduce. For example, run this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string foo = "FOO";
        switch (foo)
        {
            case "FOO":
                MessageBox.Show("Dog");
                MessageBox.Show("Cat");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Both message boxes show up. I suspect something else is going on that you're not showing us. If you can edit your question to include a short but complete program which *does* demonstrate the problem, that will be a different matter.

Comment: Does the removal of ":" after FOO make a difference? I've not got a useful enviroonment to hand to test but I'm wondering if it somehow interprets that first messagebox as part of the case and then decides it isn't the right case so skips it...

Comment: That is a significant difference, probably not useful here though. ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: I think the OP posting a short but complete which does what he claims would be the first step, to be honest... at that point we may or may not need a debugger, but until we can reproduce it there's nothing to debug.

Comment: @Jon: Sorry, I thought Chris was the OP and I meant to tell him to first debug and then ask here. Only after a minute I noticed that Chris has nothing to do with the initial question :-) That's why I removed my comment.

Comment: Your assumption is right. A try catch found me a threading issues. it wasn't the switching statement fault.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the colons. It should read:

```
switch(foo)
{
   case "FOO":
      MessageBox.Show("Dog");
      MessageBox.Show("Cat");
      break;
   case ...
   case ...
}
```

Other than that I also can't reproduce the problem. Please show more code - I'm pretty sure that you're not showing us the real cause for the error.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `":"` after the `"FOO".`

```
switch(foo)
{
   case "FOO":
      MessageBox.Show("Dog");
      MessageBox.Show("Cat");
      break;
   case ...
   case ...
}
```